# Trying to create and print elements from an array in MIPS

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, mips

I'm really struggling with mips it seems, I've read multiple tutorials on how to make arrays and access them, but whenever I try doing the listed methods, my program does nothing.

currently I have this code:

```
.data
array:  .word  1:32       # array of 32 integers
line:   .asciiz "\n"
main:   
    li   $t0, 0          # $t0 is the loop induction variable
    li   $t1, 32     # $t1 is the sentinal value for the loop
    la   $t2, array      # $9 starts as the base address of the array
                  #   and is the address of each element
    li   $t3, 1        # $12 is the value 18, to be put in desired element
for:    
    bge  $t0, $t1, end_for
    sw   $t3, ($t2)
    li   $v0, 4
    la   $a0, line
    syscall
    li   $v0, 1
    move $a0, t3
    syscall
    add  $t2, $t2, 4      # get address of next array element
    add  $t0, $0, 1      # increment loop induction variable
    b    valfor        
valfor: 
    addi $t3, $t3, 1     
    b for

end_for:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

When trying to run this, my code immediately finishes. It doesn't list any errors or do anything funny, it just says `-- program is finished running (dropped off bottom) --`

If someone could point me in the right direction as far as creating, accessing and printing an array of integers I would appreciate it a huge amount.

sites I thought I interpreted accurately to come up with my code:
http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cs354-2/onyourown/arrays.html
http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs2505/fall2010/Notes/pdf/T23.MIPSArrays.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually tried to run the code that you put in your question? It contains the line `move $a0, t3`, which won't assemble in SPIM because of the missing `$` sign (`t3` should be `$t3`).

Apart from that I see at least two problems with your code:

You have an infinite loop because of this line:

```
add  $t0, $0, 1      # increment loop induction variable
```

That just does `$t0 = 1`. It should be changed to `add $t0, $t0, 1`.

The other problem is that you've put your code in the data section. The code should be in the text section, i.e. right before `main:` you should have:

```
.text
.globl main
```

Comment: I'll definitely look over that! I thought it compiled correctly, I was using MARS on Ubuntu and it never tells me these little details. Thanks again!